# org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException;unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally - Error while executing the test suite in JENKINS

Tags: maven, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver-manager, testng.xml

I have a testNG.xml test suite that i execute as maven project, the maven command works fine when executed through my terminal in local machine, but executing the same through Jenkins gives below error.

org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException:
unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
(unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
(The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'jenkins-desktop', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.15.0-112-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_265'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
remote stacktrace: #0 0x558d443c8959

The Webdriver instance is created in @BeforeMethod, below is code and ChromeOptions i have set.

```
public static void setChromeDriverProperty() {
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();

        //Set Chrome Driver properties.
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("--headless", "--disable-gpu", "--window-size=1920,1080","--ignore-certificate-errors");
        options.addArguments("start-maximized"); // open Browser in maximized mode
        options.addArguments("disable-infobars"); // disabling info-bars
        options.addArguments("--disable-extensions"); // disabling extensions
        options.addArguments("--disable-gpu"); // applicable to windows os only
        options.addArguments("--no-sandbox", "--disable-dev-shm-usage"); // Bypass OS security model, overcome limited resource problems

        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }
```